# Should I manually close DB Connection and Statement's cursor's after a fetch?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dbal

I'm building something with Silex and [Doctrine DBAL](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/doctrine.html) using a Mysql database.

I was wondering if it considered best practice to close the cursor of a statement and database connection after one's done it. For example:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT
        `id`, `userid`, `name`, `content` 
    FROM 
        `pages` p 
    WHERE 
        p.`userid` in (?)'; 

$stmt = $conn->executeQuery(
    $sql,
    [$userIds],
    [\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY]
);

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

$stmt->closeCursor();

$conn->close();
```

I can't find any examples of this. Both the Silex and Doctrine doc's don't use the statements but they're there for a reason right?

Answer (score 2):

`$stmt->closeCursor()` [appears](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php#L28) to just be a wrapper around [`PDOStatement::closeCursor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php) and would allow you to reexecute the query if you needed to:

> PDOStatement::closeCursor() frees up the connection to the server so
>   that other SQL statements may be issued, but leaves the statement in a
>   state that enables it to be executed again.
>
> **This method is useful for database drivers that do not support
>   executing a PDOStatement object when a previously executed
>   PDOStatement object still has unfetched rows.** If your database driver
>   suffers from this limitation, the problem may manifest itself in an
>   out-of-sequence error.

In the example you posted, you are not executing multiple queries and instead closing the connection immediately afterwords. Thus, calling it is not beneficial. If you're *really* concerned about memory usage, setting `$stmt` to `null` should be more effective.

`Connection::close()` [appears](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php#L603) to just sets the connection on the object to null:

```
/**
 * Closes the connection.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function close()
{
    $this->_conn = null;
    $this->_isConnected = false;
}
```

It frees up some memory, thus making it a better practice than *not* calling it. However I would expect the benefit to be negligible as it will be closed when the script terminates anyway.

Comment: Hmm, yeah but the `$conn->close();` call is also not listed in their docs.. My question was about closing the db as well...

Comment: @Tieme, Maybe I'm not following - is `$conn` _not_ an instance of `Connection`? Is that not the "db" you are referring to?

Comment: Yes it is an instance of `Connection`, and indeed the database (connection) I was referring to.

Comment: If the doc says: `PDOStatement::closeCursor() frees up the connection to the server so that other SQL statements may be issued` then it should be called right?

Comment: @Tieme, I can see why you'd think that based on what I copied over. I've updated the answer - but the purpose for `PDOStatement::closeCursor()` is more about supporting fringe DBs than optimization. IMO, the note about setting `$stmt = null;` is overkill, but should be worth trying over closing the cursor.